# Is there anyway build php-fpm website on Bamboo CI?

Tags: php, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, bamboo

I am new to php-fpm and Bamboo server(atlassian), I have to integrate php-fpm website on bamboo Continuous Integration and Continuous deploy .

How can i build php-fpm website on Bamboo CI?

Comment: My understanding is you would add Bamboo on to an existing frontend server. On that server you would have already installed PHP, PHPUnit, web server, etc. Question is probably not a good match for StackOverflow.

Comment: Refer this link: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/getting-started-with-php-and-bamboo-289277284.html